# Adding second set of parents in an online tree at Ancestry?

Tags: ancestry.com, family-tree

I want to add a second set of parents to [someone](http://trees.ancestry.com/tree/70025770/person/30322313769?fpid=30322313769&pg=32800) in my Ancestry.com tree. I'm surprised that I'm unable to find a way to do this. I've searched online and found [references](http://boards.ancestry.com/topics.ancestry.ancsite/12349/mb.ashx) to a [relationships tab](http://ancestryforums.custhelp.com/posts/eda5d9c079) which appears to no longer exist.

There is an `+ Add Family Member` dropdown but it only has options for brother, sister, spouse, and child.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Go to edit person below their name. 
   [image]
2. Go to Relationships.
3. Click on "Add Alternative Parent".
   [image]

Answer (score 4):

UPDATED VERSION:

1. Go to your family tree
2. Click the person you want to add to
3. Click "Profile"
4. At the top right of the profile it should have a "tools" button and an "Edit" button
5. Click "Edit" and three different buttons should come down from there. One is an "edit relationship" or "add relationship" button.
6. Click the relationship button and it should pull up a screen with the current parents and that is where you can change them to adoptive or step parents or biological parents.
7. To add a new parent click "add alternative father" or "add alternative mother"

Hopefully this helps! We were looking for the new way to do it and nobody had the updated version yet.

Answer (score 1):

Since the previous answers were written, Ancestry has added the capability to display two sets of parents on a person's profile page.  Crista Cowan demonstrates this in her Barefoot Genealogist Video, [September 2019 edition, What's New at Ancestry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wi5P0_jECTY&list=PL2F65E97B57EF8279&index=2&t=0s). The segment starts shortly after 11 minutes into the video.

1. From the Edit drop-down menu (top right of the profile) choose Edit Relationships.
2. This will open an overlay window showing all the relationships for the people in the immediate family (parents, spouses, children) for the person whose profile you are on.
3. Add the new parents by clicking the plus button next to "Choose Alternate Father" or "Choose Alternate Mother".  The default setting is "Biological" but there are several other choices on a drop-down menu, including Adopted [sic], Step, and so on.
4. When adding a parent (either the first parent or an alternate) you'll get an option to create a new person, or choose someone who is already in your tree. If the person is already in the tree, start typing the name in the box and the system should prompt you with the person's name and dates.
5. Once you have multiple parents, you'll see an option to chose one as the preferred parent. This will determine which one shows in the pedigree view.
6. The new addition as of September 2019 is that a note will show on the person's profile that there are multiple sets of parents. You can see this in Crista's video around 16:15 and following. Click the down arrow next to the blue message **Additional Parent Relationships** to see the additional parents.